# Using Flex/Bison to parse underscore delimited value

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I would like to parse some input, mainly numbers, that can be delimited using underscore ( _ ) for user readability.

Ex.

- 1_0001_000  ->  1000100
- 000_000_111 -> 000000111

How would I set up my flex/yacc to do so?

Comment: You don't need bison or yacc for this, or flex either really. A simple regular expression would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential flex answer (in C):

```
DIGIT    [0-9]
%%
{DIGIT}+("_"{DIGIT}+)* {  int numUnderscores = 0;
                          for(int i = 0; i < yyleng; i++)
                            if(yytext[i] == '_')
                              numUnderscores++;
                          int stringLength = yyleng - numUnderscores + 1;
                          char *string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * stringLength);
                          /* be sure to check and ensure string isn't NULL */
                          int pos = 0;
                          for(int i = 0; i < yyleng; i++) {
                            if(yytext[i] != '_') {
                              string[pos] = yytext[i];
                              pos++;
                            }
                          }
                          return string;
                       }
```

- If you know the maximum size of the number, you could use a statically sized array instead of dynamically allocating space for the string.
- As stated before flex isn't the most efficient tool for solving this problem.  If this problem is part of a larger problem (such as a language grammar), then keep using flex.  Otherwise, there are many more efficient ways of handling this.

If you just need the string numerically, try this:

```
DIGIT    [0-9]
%%
{DIGIT}+("_"{DIGIT}+)* {  int number = 0;
                          for(int i = 0; i < yyleng; i++)
                            if(yytext[i] != '_')
                              number = (number*10) + (yytext[i]-'0');
                          return number;
                       }
```

Just be sure to check for overflow!